# How to skolemize multiple combinations of universal and existential quantifieres?

Tags: math, logic, theory, quantifiers

What is the skolemized form of (∀u∃v a(u,v)) ∧ (∀x∃y a(x,y)) ?

I am unsure, because there are different perenex normal forms possible:

- ∀u∃v ∀x∃y (a(u,v) ∧ a(x,y))
- ∀u∀x ∃v∃y (a(u,v) ∧ a(x,y))
- …

There would different skolemized forms follow:

- ∀u ∀x (a(u,f(u)) ∧ a(x,g(u,x)))
- ∀u∀x (a(u,f(u,x)) ∧ a(x,g(u,x)))

In my mind, they are not equivalent to each other. Or am I here wrong?

Comment: Seems like terrible offtopic to me :-)

Comment: Offtopic - yes, because it is not directly programming related.
But logic is a part of my course of studies computer sciences, so I think it is not terrible offtopic. ;-)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mathematical logic, which is more appropriate at math.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, prenex normal forms are not unique for a given FO formula, and,
correspondingly, Skolemizations are not unique. A simpler example for the
same "scope escape" I think you are trying to show is the formula ∃xAx →
∃yBy, with prenex forms ∀x∃y (Ax → By) and ∃y∀x (Ax → By), and respective
skolemizations ∀x (¬ Ax ∨ Bf(x)) and ∀x (¬ Ax ∨ B a), with a a constant.

Now, the pertinent question is whether the non-equivalence of those
formulae matters for your particular problem. If it does, perhaps
Skolemization is not the best tool for you: [Skolemization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolemization) is a process
designed to preserve satisfiability of formulae, sometimes at the expense
of equivalence.

(and in any case, it is a good exercise to see why distinct skolemizations
of a single formula are equisatisfiable, if only on the examples above)

Comment: I'm thinking about this problem, because I have a bit more complex problem, that I try to solve. The intention is to use resolution to proof if the knowledge base can let to a given assumption. So the basic formula I try to disprove with resolution is "A ∧ B ∧ ¬C". I heared, that I can skolemize the parts of the formula one by one (1. "A", 2. "B" and 3. "¬C") and put them then together. But I don't know if this is true and if it is, why? What allows me to do this?
I could figure that, if I do a part-skolemization then, rearange ∀s/∃s and skolemize the rest, but I don't know if I could do that…